# 3D plot from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hi I am currently learning how to do plots in Tex and I found a problem which I cant solve. I would like to do 3D surface plot from file but all what I get is  a 3D line. 
For learning purpose I used an generic example from pgfplots documentation (function of {5*x*sin(2*deg(x)) * y};) and then tried to plot it from the file which contains data of this function.

\begin{figure}[!ht]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,
colormap/greenyellow]

\addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies]
table [x=x, y=y, z=z, col sep=tab]{3D.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

File 3D.txt contains:

```
z   x   y
0   0   0
0.001247918 0.05    0.05
0.009933467 0.1 0.1
0.033246023 0.15    0.15
0.077883668 0.2 0.2
0.149820481 0.25    0.25
0.254089113 0.3 0.3
0.394583333 0.35    0.35
0.573884873 0.4 0.4
0.793118496 0.45    0.45
1.051838731 0.5 0.5
1.347951132 0.55    0.55
1.677670355 0.6 0.6
2.035516667 0.65    0.65
2.414351838 0.7 0.7
2.80545465  0.75    0.75
3.19863553  0.8 0.8
3.582389128 0.85    0.85
3.944082905 0.9 0.9
4.270179146 0.95    0.95
4.546487134 1   1
```

Then what I get is on the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy2Hg.png)[image: Plot What I get]

and it should be like this

[image: Plot what I want to get]

I am very thankful for your advices.

Comment: You only have `z` values for `y=x`, so there are not enough values to generate a surface.

Comment: You are right. I Solved it, it needs values (z,y) for each x. I did not realize it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.